# Why do I miss my own votes after any down vote to a question?

Tags: bug

I have found it that after any downvote by me from first day of getting this privilege I miss my votes immediately. It happened first time in EL&U then in the other forums. I found it doesn't happen for the other users. By this I cannot use my right like the other users to keep the site far from of abusive actions and non constructive questions. It causes the other users find a more powerful ability to control my scores in low amounts in all forums and try a one-way action against me. It is happening for me during one month which I have joined SE. It seems like a bug for me!

P.S: I am not talking why I miss my votes when the other users downvote me but I asked why by downvoting a non constructive **questions** by me it causes the same effect on my scores immediately without any changing in my questions/answers scores. It seems like I am decreasing my own votes too after giving any negative vote to the other user's question automatically!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you (or anyone else) downvotes an answer, you have a single point of reputation removed. You can find this information in the FAQ, in the section about [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

[image: Circled downvote bit]

You don't see it for others because it would provide a way of indirectly gathering evidence about who might be downvoting your posts, and voting is supposed to be anonymous. But the penalty is assessed for everyone, we just can't see it for other users.

As for the downvotes when you downvote questions, I do not see any evidence that you are receiving serial or targeted downvotes. If you have some more specific information that you want to share, I can look into it further.

I have brought the matter to the attention of the community mods, since they have more tools at their disposal than I do. If they find that someone is targeting you, the downvotes will be reversed.

Comment: Sorry but it seems you didn't get my question! In that section is not any explanation about "when you give a negative vote to another user immediately it causes the same for yourself! Right? That section in your FAQ is only describing "when the other user have a negative vote to you ( your questions and answers ) you will miss your scores. and another matter that after any down vote by me to another person I found the history in my own profile so it was completely obvious for the other users to find it however my question was about something else.

Comment: I added a picture. Hopefully that will clarify it for you. It comes from the FAQ. In the scenario you describe, you would be the voter who receives the -1.

Comment: But when I down vote the question of another user I miss one vote too! what about this? And about the history of this which I saw it in my own profile much of the time and It was obvious to the other users too?

Comment: @user You can see it in your profile, but nobody else can.

Comment: About answers and history it made it clear for me thanks! But what about down votes to questions?

Comment: To my knowledge, this was changed [last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free). It's possible that it was changed back.

Comment: +1 So could you search to find out it? It is only month that I am here beside of fireworks which I made I didn't have enough time to find out these matters. I think it can be an important question to find the matter and avoid of it or adapt ourselves with it. :)